# PHPUnit / Lumen always returns 404

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, lumen

When I create a PHPUnit test case in Laravel Lumen and call the `visit('/')` function, PHPUnit always returns a 404 error code.

I have the following code to test the weird behavior:

```
class TestCase extends Laravel\Lumen\Testing\TestCase {
    protected $baseUrl = 'https://google.com'; // this used to be my own url but even this doesn't work.

    public function createApplication() {
        return require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
    }
}

class CountryTest extends TestCase {
    public function testIndex() {
        $this->visit('/');
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong or how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by including my routes with `require` instead of `require_once`.

Comment: This is very strange. I'm running Lumen in Docker and this was the only way to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by returning the `APP_URL` to its original value in `.env` file.

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Or just change it to the localhost address you are using.